# HP Laptop / Docking Station clean connection and disconnection on Debian based LinuxOS?

Tags: laptop, deepin

**My Hardware & Software**

---

Hardware : **HP Elitebook 2570p** ...
Docking Station : **HP 2570 A9B77AA Docking Station**

Software : **Debian based Linux Deepin V20.x**

---

Thanks to Debian and Deepin, the docking station worked out of the box, it connects and works fine(USB ports and VGA ports have been tested) ... eSata however i've not been able to get it working(would appreciate if anybody directed me to a place which can help be get this working as well).

As already stated connection and working is not an issue, But disconnecting and getting my laptop working off of the docking is big challenge to the point of Nightmare. I fear the Deepin's window manager(which uses KWIN)/Display Server may be causing this.

**What I would look forward from the community ?**

As the disconnection from my docking station isn't working, I would appreciate if the community helped me get my laptop dispossessed of the docking station high it goes into.

When there is a power outage, its the worst of nightmares, as my laptop is rendered unusable until the power is back. besides of course  disengaging the docking slider which also renders the laptop unusable.

Any probing commands whose output you'd like to see off of my system, kindly post those commands in the comments section and i'll append my question with the additional data to help the community better diagnose the issue.

Currently I've fiddle with the command

`kwin_x11 --replace` - to restart kwin

`killall dde-dock` - to reload the dock

invoke the KB shortcut to toggle '`Windows Effect`' setting ...

in no specific order, sometimes it works and most other times it does not.

Thanks for looking into the issue, appreciate and look forward to a way(a script or a set of commands that will let me disconnect my laptop from the docking station especially when there is a power outage) a bypass of sorts.

Comment: Attention all units, we have a _'Code Silver'_ -  A violent docking-station has taken AIAMUZZs laptop hostage..

Comment: hahaha LOL ... you just read my mind and the hidden agony, as that's exactly how i feel when i try to disconnect my laptop with my laptop behaving all erratic.

I am hoping a powerful 'Linux Oracle' can intercede between my laptop and docking station and if things don't work out then 'exorcism' performed by a Linux priest of High Order may the last option.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm far from being an expert regarding KWIN/KDE, hopefully some one here can give you some insights. Another option you could try is posting your issue on https://forum.kde.org/

Comment: does the docking station contain a storage device?

Comment: @jsotola ... the docking station in itself does not have a storage device, but by extension of the many ports it supports ... FYI I haven't connected any storage device to it, in case you want to rule out its mischief in this.

Comment: If its any help in identifying the issue i am facing, If i disable the 'Windows Effect' my laptop is usable provided i keep the Windows Effect disabled. The moment i try to re-enable 'Windows Effect' after disconnecting the dock the issue returns and my laptop is unusable(the original isse)